# Argument of the Riemann zeta function on Re(s)=1

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

I refer to the lovely answer to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447027/orientation-of-zeta-zeroes-on-the-critical-line). Is there an exact formula for the argument of the Riemann zeta function? Specifically, I would like to know the arguments along the line Re$(s)=1$. Some numerical computations/visualizations would be nice too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(*first* : Glad you liked the answer!)

I'll use the standard notation $\;s:=\sigma+it\;$ (with $\sigma$ and $\,t>0$ real values).

Let's begin with a picture of the complex orbits $\;t\in (2,42)\mapsto\zeta(\sigma+it)\;$ for $\,\sigma=0, \dfrac 12, 1,\dfrac 32$ respectively :

[image: pict1]

**Qualitative discussion** :

- for $\;\sigma<\dfrac 12\;$ the loops turn around the origin $0$ (for negative values of $\sigma$ the loops look more and more like an outgoing spiral)
- as $\;\sigma\;$ approaches $\dfrac 12$ all the loops miraculously cross (or seem to cross...) the origin (to simplify the 'wording' I'll suppose the R.H. true!)
- for larger values of $\;\sigma\;$ the loops will concentrate more and more near the value $1$.

---

If we imagine a line going from the origin to the complex point $\zeta(\sigma+it)$ we may conjecture that for $\,\sigma\le \dfrac 12\,$ the (continuous) phase will decrease (the rotation being clockwise for $t\gg 1$) indefinitely as $t\,$ grows while for larger values of $\sigma$ the phase will only oscillate between $-\pi$ and $+\pi$.
The following green, red and blue curves show the principal argument for $\,\sigma=0, \dfrac 12, 1\,$ :
[image: pict3]

The principal argument is illustrated instead of the (continuous) phase (both were [illustrated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3eMV.png) in your link for $\,\sigma=\dfrac 12$). This implies that there will be a jump of $\pm\pi$ for every zero of $\,\zeta\,$ and a jump from $-\pi$ to $+\pi$ after each loop for $\sigma<\dfrac 12$.

In the case $\sigma=\dfrac 12\,$ the phase is known as the very regular [Riemann–Siegel theta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Siegel_theta_function) $-\theta(t)$ from $\,\displaystyle\zeta\left(\frac 12+it\right)=Z(t)\,e^{-\large{i\theta(t)}}\;$ (c.f. your [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447027/orientation-of-zeta-zeroes-on-the-critical-line) or the demonstration to follow). Anyway, from the picture, we may doubt that such a simple solution exists in the case $\,\sigma=1\,$ or even $\,\sigma\neq\frac 12$...
The phase for $\,\sigma=1\,$ appears to 'follow' the principal argument of $\,\zeta\,$ for $\sigma=\dfrac 12$ and thus to have the complexity of the [amplitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_function) $Z(t)$ rather than the simplicity of the phase $-\theta(t)$.

---

**Quantitative discussion** :

Let's start with the symmetric version of the [functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Riemann%27s_functional_equation) $\;\xi(s)=\xi(1-s)\;$ as presented by Riemann with [$\,\xi(s)$ defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_Xi_function) by :
$$\tag{1}\xi(s)=\frac {s(s-1)}2 \,\Gamma\left(\frac s2\right)\,\pi^{-s/2}\,\zeta(s)$$

Since $\,\dfrac {s(s-1)}2=\dfrac {(1-s)(1-s-1)}2\,$ we may remove this common factor from $\;\xi(s)=\xi(1-s)\;$ and expand the logarithm of the result as :

$$\log\Gamma\left(\frac s2\right)-\log(\pi)\,\frac s2+\log \zeta\left(s\right)=\log\Gamma\left(\frac {1-s}2\right)-\log(\pi)\,\frac {1-s}2+\log \zeta\left(1-s\right)$$
or (putting the $\,\log\zeta\;$ terms at the left) :
$$\tag{2}\log \zeta\left(s\right)-\log \zeta\left(1-s\right)=\log\Gamma\left(\frac {1-s}2\right)-\log\Gamma\left(\frac s2\right)+\log(\pi)\left(s-\frac 12\right)$$

With the functional equation some usual relations like $\tag{3}\log\zeta(\overline{s})=\overline{\log\zeta(s)},\;\log\Gamma(\overline{s})=\overline{\log\Gamma(s)}\;$ and other useful [properties of $\Gamma$](https://web.archive.org/web/20151018095000/http://people.math.sfu.ca/%7Ecbm/aands/page_256.htm) will be helpful.

1. Let's consider $\,s=\sigma+it\,$ and study $(2)$ in the specific case $\,\sigma=\dfrac 12$ :
   $$\log \zeta\left(\frac 12+it\right)-\log \zeta\left(\frac 12-it\right)=\log\Gamma\left(\frac {\frac 12-it}2\right)-\log\Gamma\left(\frac {\frac 12+it}2\right)+\log(\pi)it$$
   From $(3)$ we are simply subtracting a complex and its complex conjugate (twice) so that this becomes :
   $$2\,\Im\log \zeta\left(\frac 12+it\right)=-2\,\Im\log\Gamma\left(\frac {\frac 12+it}2\right)+\log(\pi)it$$
   i.e. the classical [Riemann–Siegel theta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Siegel_theta_function) for the case $\,\sigma=\dfrac 12$ :
   $$\tag{4}\boxed{-\theta(t):=\arg \zeta\left(\frac 12+it\right)=-\arg\Gamma\left(\frac 14+\frac{it}2\right) +   \frac {\log(\pi)}2\;t}\quad t\in \mathbb{R}$$
2. Let's examine $(2)$ with $\,\sigma=0\,$ and thus provide a link with the case of interest $\,\sigma=1$ :
   $$\tag{5}\log \zeta\left(it\right)-\log \zeta\left(1-it\right)=\log\Gamma\left(\frac {1-it}2\right)-\log\Gamma\left(\frac {it}2\right)+\log(\pi)\left(it-\frac 12\right)$$
   We will again deduce the argument from the imaginary part and (using the [Legendre duplication formula](https://web.archive.org/web/20151018095000/http://people.math.sfu.ca/%7Ecbm/aands/page_256.htm) $(6.1.18)$ for $\Gamma\,$) :
   \begin{align}
   \arg\zeta(it)+\arg\zeta(1+it)&=-\arg\left(\Gamma\left(\frac {it}2\right)\Gamma\left(\frac {1+it}2\right)\right)+\log(\pi)\,t\\
   &=-\arg\left(\sqrt{\pi}\,2^{1-it}\,\Gamma(it)\right)+\log(\pi)\,t\\
   \end{align}
   Since $\;-\arg\left(2^{-it}\right)=\log(2)\,t\;$ this becomes simply :
   $$\tag{6}\boxed{\arg\zeta(it)+\arg\zeta(1+it)=-\arg\Gamma\left(it\right) +   \log(2\pi)\;t\,}\quad t\in \mathbb{R}$$
   $$\text{(up to a $\,2\,\pi\,k\,$ constant depending of normalization)}$$
   or the rather neat :
   $$\tag{7}\boxed{\;\arg\left((2\,\pi)^{-it}\Gamma(it)\,\zeta(it)\,\zeta(1+it)\right)=0\;}\quad t\in \mathbb{R}$$
   which appears deep until noticing that the usual functional equation
   $$\tag{8}\zeta(1+it)=2(2\pi)^{it}\sin\left(\frac {\pi}2(1+it)\right)\Gamma(-it)\zeta(-it)$$
   and some Gamma relations transform $(7)$ in the trivial $\quad\arg(\zeta(+it)\,\zeta(-it))=0$.

$\Gamma(it)\,$ is very regular (see the [pictures](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/762066/derivative-of-riemann-zeta-is-this-inequality-true/762090#762090) along the line $x=0$) but of course $\;\arg\zeta(it)\,$ is not simpler than  $\;\arg\zeta(1+it)$...

Can we learn something more from the real part of $(5)$ ? Well that
$$\tag{9}\left|\frac{\zeta(it)}{\zeta(1+it)}\right|=\sqrt{\frac {t\;\tanh\left(\frac{\pi}2\,t\right)}{2\,\pi}}$$

---

**Some references** to recent work concerning $\,\zeta(1+it)\,$ (for very different points of view) :

- Andersson (2012) ["On the zeta function on the line $\Re(s) = 1$"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.4336) (with references to earlier work)
- Granville and Soundararajan (2005) ["Extreme values of $|\zeta(1+it)|$"](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0501232)
- Lamzouri (2008) ["The two dimensional distribution of values of $\zeta(1+it)$"](https://arxiv.org/abs/0801.3692)
- Trudgian (2012) ["A new upper bound for $|\zeta(1+it)|$"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.6743)
- de Reyna, Brent, van de Lune (2014) ["A note on the real part of the Riemann zeta-function"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.4910) (values of $t$ such that $\Re \zeta(1+it)<0$)
- following this interesting paper by van de Lune (1983) ["Some observations concerning the zero-curves of the real and imaginary parts of zeta"](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Some-observations-concerning-the-zero-curves-of-the-Lune-de/33718686bdb83d26f3d4767c85d233cde537dd3c) (the argument of zeta is considered there)

An old paper of Wintner (1936) could also be of interest ["The almost periodic behavior of the function $1/\zeta(1+it)$"](https://doi.org/10.1215/S0012-7094-36-00235-1) and many others of course...

Comment: Wonderful! Could I ask what you use to produce your graphs?

Comment: Thanks! I use an old version of MuPAD (included in Matlab these days) and like the 3D pictures produced like [these](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138084/regularization-of-a-divergent-integral/139093#139093). For more precise pictures (and $\LaTeX$ fonts!) [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net) is excellent, [some examples](http://asy.marris.fr/asymptote/Surfaces_3D) to add to the 3D curve for $\zeta$ from your link I think. Cheers,

Comment: Here's a follow up question I think is easy for you: how would the answer change if instead one considered the completed $\pi^{-s/2}\Gamma(s/2)\zeta(s)$ at $s=1+it$? From what little I can tell, completing the zeta function seems to make the values outside of $|t|<1$ quite small.

Comment: @TianAnWong: Sorry but I don't understand your question : since $\;\xi(s)=\xi(1-s)\;$ the common factor of $\;\xi\,$ i.e. $\,\dfrac {s(s-1)}2=\dfrac {(1-s)(-s)}2\,$ disappears and plays no role ($\,\xi\,$ isn't involved in the following but $\,\zeta\,$ only). Other formulations can't change the results (up to some equivalent rewriting of course).

Comment: Our discussion so far has been about the argument of $\zeta(1+it)$, and I'm wondering what how the argument of $\pi^{-(1+it)/2}\Gamma((1+it)/2)\zeta(1+it)$ looks like. I hope that clarifies the question.

Comment: Oh ok then it will add $\;-\log(\pi)\frac t2+\arg(\Gamma((1+it)/2)\;$. Not sure that it will be simpler than the graph (in blue) from the picture which appears bounded in the range I tested (I mean the continuous expansion of the argument of $\zeta(1+it)$) but I don't know more about this at this point.

Comment: I found the regularity of the argument for $\,\sigma>\dfrac 12\,$ rather interesting. Concerning $\sigma=1$ see too [MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/219292/behaviour-of-zeta1-it-zeta1it). (oops you are involved! :=))

Comment: Juan's remark (de Reyna from my ref.) in the MO link made me think that I should have added the Kotnik (2004) reference ["Computational estimation of the order of the constant $\beta(1)$ characterizing the order of $zeta(1+it)$"](http://lbk.fe.uni-lj.si/pdfs/mcom2008.pdf) with the indication (at the start) "$|\zeta(1+it)|$ takes arbitrary large values, as well as values arbitrary close to zero" (the PNT forbids the equality). This and Juan's comment make me think that, from time to time as $t$ increases, we should obtain a loop around the origin in my first picture for $\sigma=1$.