# In Pursuit of the Modulus of the Riemann Zeta Function in the Critical Strip

Tags: riemann-zeta

Notation: $\zeta(s) = \zeta(x+it)$

In http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/136881/MathSlov_53-2003-2_3.pdf      the following inequality was proven:

$$
\left|\zeta\left(\frac 1 2 - d+it\right)\right| \ge \left| \zeta\left( \frac 1 2 + d + it \right) \right| \text{ for } 0\le d \le \frac 1 2 \text{ and } t \ge 2\pi+1.
$$

Letting $d = 1/2$, we get:

$$
|\zeta(it) \ge |\zeta(1+it)|.
$$

The question concerns the relation between $|\zeta(1+it)|$ and $|\zeta(x+it)|$ . Specifically, is the inequality below true:

$$
|\zeta(x+it)| \le |\zeta(1+it)|
$$

The above inequality will complete the ordering of the three moduli as follows:

$$
|\zeta(x+it)| \le |\zeta(1+it)| \le |\zeta(it)|
$$

Thank you for your support.

Comment: Thanks Michael for editing

Comment: @ hass : you know that the first inequality follows trivially from the functional equation $\zeta(s) = \chi(s) \zeta(1-s)$ ?

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't know and I don't know how it does.I'll appreciate an explanation how. Thanks

Comment: read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#The_functional_equation and if you read french, the article in french is much better

Comment: I read both versions of the article which assert that: Modulus{Zeta(it)] = A(t) * Modulus[Zeta(1+it)] without explaining how this result was obtained. Also A(t) > 1 needs to be proven. In any case, the proof I provided is much easier. I am more interested in a proof of the second inequality. Any thoughts about it would be very helpful. Thanks again

Comment: Concerning the relation between the modulus of $\zeta(it)$ and $\zeta(1+it)$ see $(9)$ in this [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1483780/argument-of-the-riemann-zeta-function-on-res-1/1495533#1495533) (from the real part of $(5)$).

Comment: Thanks Raymond for the reference. It's a great and direct approach to deal with the relation. The factor B(t) on the RHS of the answer needs to be greater than 1, to prove the relationship. Now what remains to prove is the second inequality. Any reference or idea about how to prove it will be very useful. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad it helped @Hass Saidane (I should have added to divide $(6.1.30)$ and $(6.1.29)$ at [page $256$ of A&S](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_256.htm) to conclude). Concerning $|\zeta(x+it)| \le |\zeta(1+it)|$ it doesn't appear right in general since $|\zeta(x+it)|$ will be as small as you wish near a zero of $\zeta$ compared to $|\zeta(1+it)|$ but the ratio becomes larger than $1$ between the zeros as illustrated in the ![linded picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/30bb2.gif) of $\;t\mapsto \left|\dfrac {\zeta(\sigma+it)}{\zeta(1+it)}\right|$ for $\sigma=\frac 12$ and $t\in[0,30]$.

Comment: (the symmetry around $\frac12$ of the inequality from the paper appears important!). Supposing $x>1$ [doesn't look](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20abs%28zeta%282%2BI*t%29%2Fzeta%281%2BI*t%29%29) more promising. Sorry...

Comment: Thanks Raymond for the explanation. How about this inequality:  Modulus[Zeta(x + it)] < Modulus[Zeta(it)]. It is supported by numerical results. Do you have an idea on how to prove it?

Comment: @Hass Saidane: you are right this one is much more promising but I didn't find a proof. In fact I would even conjecture something more precise for $x\in(0,1)$ :
$$\left|\zeta(x+it)\right|\le\left(\frac {2\,\pi}{t\;\tanh\left(\frac{\pi}2\,t\right)}\right)^{x/2}\left|\zeta(it)\right|$$

Comment: Thanks Raymond. It's supported by numerical test results  (see:  http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/136881/MathSlov_53-2003-2_3.pdf , pg 150). Your conjecture is great. Is the factor A(t) < 1?  A proof would be nice, even without the factor A(t). The  only close reference I found was in Tichtmarsh's "The Zeta Function of Riemann", p.20:  Zeta(x + it) = O(t^ (1/2- x/2) logt) for 0 <= x <= 1. At x = 0, we get: Zeta(it) = O(t^ 1/2)logt) so that: Modulus[Zeta(x + it)] < Modulus[Zeta(it)]. Is this correct,  general? Thanks again.

Comment: I fear that relations like $\zeta(it) = O(t^{1/2}\log t)$ or better ones in the [French Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction_zêta_de_Riemann#Estimations_sur_Re.28s.29_.3D_0) won't help much (because of the implicit arbitrary coefficient in $O()$). Perhaps that subtraction $\zeta(x+it)-\zeta(it)$ or quotient expansions could return the wished results... who knows? Good luck anyway,

Comment: Thank you very much you for your help Raymond. If you ever get a reference or a proof for your conjecture, please pass it on.  Thanks again.

Comment: I am on Linkedin if you'd like to connect and prove the Riemann Hypothesis