# Riemann Zeta Function for $\Re(s)=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

All the sources I have read talk about continuation from $Re(s)>1$ to $Re(s)>0$ then $Re(s)<0$ $(s\neq 1)$. What about $Re(s)=0$? Where does that go?

Comment: The functional equation implies a symmetry between the cases $\Re(s)\ge 1$ and $\Re(s)\le 0$. For some results see for example $(9)$ [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1483780/argument-of-the-riemann-zeta-function-on-res-1).

Answer (score 2):

the [functional equation is proven first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#The_functional_equation) for $Re(s) \in \ ]0,1[$, but then by analytic continuation it is valid everywhere (except at $s=1$ or $s=0$ of course).

you can also [analytically continuate $\zeta(s)$ from](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Mellin_transform) $$\Gamma(s) \zeta(s) = \int_0^1 \left(\frac{x}{e^x-1}-\sum_{k=0}^K \frac{B_k}{k!} x^k\right)x^{s-2}dx + \int_1^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1}dx + \sum_{k=0}^K \frac{B_k}{k!} \frac{1}{s+k-1}$$

valid for every $Re(s) > - K$ and not a negative integer (with $B_k$ the [Bernouilli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number))

and don't forget that in complex analysis, we don't consider functions but [analytic continuation of functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation).