# Riemann Zeta function with a complex exponent

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, riemann-zeta

As a part of my math project, I am working on Infinite series and Riemann Zeta function. I am very new to this function, and am still studying how this series behaves. I am trying to work the problem out when
$s= 1+i$ i.e. $\zeta(1+i)$.

Since Re(s) =1, so it should be outside critical strip. But I do not know more than this, and  I looked up online as well on the previous queries related to complex exponentials as well as Riemann Zeta function, but found nothing to help me move forward. I do not know how to work with complex exponential in an infinite series.
$\zeta(1+i)= \sum^\infty _i = 1+\frac{1}{2^{1+i} }+\frac{1}{3^{1+i} }+\frac{1}{4^{1+i} }+...$

So far I have done this using the exponential and logarithmic property, and the Euler representation.  I would be super grateful if you have anything that will help me go to further steps after this:

$a^z=e^{z\cdot \ln(a)}=e^{(x+iy)\ln(a)}=e^{x \cdot \ln(a) } \cdot e^{i y \ln(a)}$

Now using this we get,

$2^{1+i}= e^{\ln(2)} \cdot e^{i \ln(2)} = 2e^{i \ln(2)}= 2(\cos{\ln(2)}+ i \sin{\ln(2)})$

And for $3^{1+i}= e^{\ln(3)} \cdot e^{i \ln(3)} = 2e^{i \ln(3)}= 3(\cos{\ln(3)}+ i \sin{\ln(3)})$

I am not sure how would I use this back in the series to examine anything.

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for? Do you want a method on how to compute the actual value, or a different series which converges to $\zeta(1+i)$? [This](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=zeta%281%2Bi%29) might be a good place to start...

Comment: Your expansions of $2^{1+i}$ and $3^{1+i}$ are correct! If you're interested in the infinite series itself, would it suffice for you to understand $\zeta(2+i)$ instead of $\zeta(1+i)$? The convergence of $\zeta(1+i)$ is more delicate (it converges conditionally).

Comment: @GregMartin The series $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} n^{-s}$ diverges for all $s$ with $\operatorname{Re} s \leqslant 1$.

Comment: @GregMartin - yes, you are correct. I am interested in examining the infinite series, so $\zeta(2+i)$ would definitely suffice. Do you have any suggestions on how I can approach it?

Comment: @RomainS Yes, I am looking for a method that helps me to show how $\zeta(2+1)$ or any $\zeta(z)$ outside the critical strip would behave. I need to formally show the process for at least one of the values for the infinite series.

Comment: But what exactly do you mean by "behave"?

Comment: @optimistic_mathematician If this is for a school math project, I would highly suggest looking at $\zeta(2)$ instead of this. Despite its apparent simplicity, it is actually a very interesting problem (hence a very well documented problem). See [this introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem), as well as one of my all time favorite youtube videos [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-o3eB9sfls). Hope this helps.

Comment: @RomainS and GregMartin I am sorry I am not sure how to clarify about this. For my math project, I am trying to work out the full process of showing Riemann Zeta function with a complex exponent. I have already looked at $\zeta(2)= \frac{\pi^2}{6}$ before posting here and was hoping to use similar approach.

Comment: You may be interested too by this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1495533/21783) with the result that $\zeta(1+i)$ (related links may be of interest too) may be rewritten in function of $\zeta(i)$ (cf $(6)$ and $(9)$ for the argument and modulus relations or $(5)$ directly). Studying $\,\zeta(i)\,$ appears thus interesting too even if  the most studied one will remain $\,\zeta\left(\frac 12+i\right)$ since it produces a real function once multiplied by $e^{i\theta(t)}$ with $\theta$ defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Siegel_theta_function#Gram_points)!